# How to optimize performance using instancing in a scene full of skinned-mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’m working on a web tower defense game based on three.js. Now I’m stuck at optimizing the performance.

My game loads two GLTF models as enemy and tower, both have skinned-mesh. When the player creates a tower or the game spawns an enemy, I use `THREE.AnimationUtils.clone` to clone the loaded model. Then I add this cloned model to the scene. For animation, I use `THREE.AnimationObjectGroup` to animate all the enemies.

This results in an average of 370 draw-calls per frame in the performance test with the scene loaded with 45 towers and 70 enemies, which is a nightmare for the game.

I think maybe using instancing can optimize the performance because every tower and enemy share the same model and state in each frame, but only rotation and position are different. But after I studied some examples using instancing, there is no example using instancing with skinned-mesh. (There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465257/three-js-skinned-skeletal-mesh-instances-animations-and-blending), but the result here doesn't mention any method with instancing.)

Is there any chance that this can be done with three.js, or some other solution for this situation?

## Update

After researched more I found some concepts maybe can help me to implement instancing with skinned-mesh.

### Concept

The original post [here](https://blog.csdn.net/leonwei/article/details/77387357?fbclid=IwAR0_ZM3qVplPal-xoVEHv8rUvnqin2dX2wf80Jub7SvdVyMK-RbgC9OsKBc) implement skinned-mesh with instancing in Unity. (It's written in Chinese, I translated the main concept in the following.)

After loaded a skinned-mesh, it has an initial state with all vertices (for clarity, each initial vertex denote as `PLT` in the following). In any frame of the animation, the final position of `PLT` (denote as `PI`) equals to a series of matrix multiplication `PI = (M_rootlocal * ... * M_2_3 * M_1_2 * M_bind_1 * PLT) + (M_rootlocal * ... * M_2_3 * M_1_2 * M_bind_2 * PLT) + (...)`

- `M_bind_1` is the bone-binding matrix of bone 1.
- `M_m_n` means the transformation of bone `m` relative to it's initial state under the coordinate system of bone `n`.

For simplify, use `M_f_i = M_rootlocal * ... * M_2_3 * M_1_2 * M_bind_i` to represent the transformation. `M_f_i` means bone-binding matrix of bone `i` after multiplication at frame `f`, so `PI = (M_f_1 * PLT) + (M_f_2 * PLT) + (...)` Once we know `M_f_i`, we can calculate the position of every vertex in frame `f`.

The process above can be done inside GPU by passing `M_f_i` which wrap as a texture. (Under the premise that the skinned-mesh needs to animate around 10 animations and less amount of bones, the require memory is about 0.75Mb.). Finally, we can pass different frame number `f` to each instance to render skinned-mesh with animation in one draw-call.

### Implement with three.js

I haven't build an example code yet because I don't know the concept can work on WebGL or not (also I'm not familiar with GLSL), but I think the way to implement it with three.js can done as the following.

1. Follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015987/three-js-bake-skeleton-transform-into-geometry) to get `M_f_i`.
2. Use `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry` and `THREE.RawShaderMaterial`.

   - In `uniforms` pass initial geometry, `M_f_i` and texture.
   - In `vertexShader` process `PI = (M_f_1 * PLT) + (M_f_2 * PLT) + (...)`.
   - In `fragmentShader` process texture (I have no idea how to do it).
3. Pass `f` and other instance attribute using `THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute`.

### Problem

- Where is `M_f` and how to get it by `THREE.AnimationClip` in step 1?
- How to index each `PLT` (vertex in geometry)?
- How to deal with texture?
- How to deal with hierarchy `Object3D` (`Object3D.children` have `THREE.Mesh` and `THREE.SkinnedMesh` at the same time)?

I need someone to tell me this idea works in three.js or not, and how to solve the problem above.

[image: Screenshot of the performance test]

[image: Analysis using Chrome dev tool]

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was a Geometry or Mesh **Merge** function that was really helping me in the past with such a cases. I recommend you search in that direction.

There are many counterparts to its usage such as loosing the individuality of each 3d object you use but when possible you should use it for static elements like environment objects, in other cases it may be also useful if your individual objects/towers are based on many single 3d objects in the way that they become just one...

From my experience (could vary a lot depending on each computer and size of 3d viewport) at the end you should never have more than 50 (simple) 3d objects in front of your visible camera area and reuse all materials, geometries, mesh... otherwise you'll end up having a very poor performance as soon as something fun is happening in your game.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Appreciate your reply! I think ```merge``` is a good way for environment objects, but it will hard to implement to the dynamic objects such as enemy and tower because their behavior is depends on the user. I have simply the model before using it. The enemy model contains 3 ```THREE.Bone``` and 1 ```THREE.SkinnedMesh```. The tower model contains 2 ```THREE.Mesh```, 1 ```THREE.Bone``` and 1 ```THREE.SkinnedMesh```. All models have simplified its geometry.

Comment: Why do you need a `Bone` and a `SkinnedMesh` in your tower? Shouldn't it simply need 2 `Mesh`es for the base and rotating turret?

Comment: There are some animations for the barrel part, which use ```Bone``` to control the behaviors. @Marquizzo