# Blender: How to correctly export gltf/glb with armature applied

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

I am having a persistent issue when exporting `glb` and `gltf` models from blender (**2.79**) that have armature applied.

I am using [this exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter).

Exporting the model with an armature NOT applied gives me the expected result (ie it appears as it does in Blender) but as soon as I apply an armature (before I have even added any animation) the model exports with all the shapes rotated.

There is at least some consistency to the problem in that it appears as though all the shapes are rotated through **90 degrees on the X axis** (although some are positive and some are negative).

To compare I have exported a `glb` with no armature, a `glb` with armature, and an `obj` with armature just to check that there is no issue with my original file. (I have done the same with `gltf` just in case. You can see a screenshot of that comparison below brought into a-frame.

[image: comparing obj and glb files with and without armature]

Here is a side view for ease of comparison. You can see how the individual shapes are flipped 90 on the x axis.

[image: side view]

[Here](https://dear-gopher.glitch.me/) as well is a link to that aframe scene

[And here](https://cdn.glitch.com/c57361a5-6ebe-4007-95ba-5499a0f13f2f%2Flamp_fresh.blend.zip?1547313432871) is a link to a zip of the blender file

I have looked at many similar issues that suggest applying all rotation/scale etc. tidying up the model etc. I have done all that and tidied up my model as much as I know how. It seems as though the model and armature is ok as the `obj` export works fine.

I have seen similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491653/why-is-blender-rigged-animation-distorted-when-exported-as-gltf) but they are mostly to do with distortion of models once animated. I have worked backwards to understand the root of the problem and it does seem that simply applying the armature is what explodes the model in this way.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an export setting I am missing?

Any help greatly appreciated as ever. And if any more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: I would suggest testing on the newer exporter (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) and filing a bug if the issue still appears. OBJ doesn't include the armature — the format doesn't support animation — so that may be why you see something different.

Comment: Hi Don, thanks for your response. That makes sense about the obj. I tried the same process with newer exporter in 2.8 and the results were even more unexpected, it just collapsed all the model parts flat on the floor. Can I use the new exporter in 2.79? I tried it once and had some issues but it was a while ago..

Comment: Having the same problem with Blender 2.8 and the latest version of GLTF-Blender-IO as of today. I can't find any docs on the repo that suggests ways to fix this or that I'm doing it wrong.